# How to use stdin to give data to rankmirrors command

Tags: bash, arch-linux, pacman, ripgrep

Probably a rooky question, but I have seen that the "rankmirrors" command can use the **stdin** input. But when I run the following command (which retrieve all URL in use in the "mirrorslist" file to the "rankmirrors"), I get an error:

```
$ rg -e "^Server" /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist | rg -oe "https.*"  | rankmirrors -t
Must specify URL, mirrorfile, or stdin.
```

There is another way to use the previous command **stdout** as current **stdin** of the command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common convention for telling "read from stdin" for programs that normally expect a filename or URL specified on the command line is to specify just a single minus sign in place of the filename/URL. The `rankmirrors` command supports this convention, so:

```
rg -e "^Server" /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist | rg -oe "https.*"  | rankmirrors -t -
```

Reference: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/mirrors#Fetching_and_ranking_a_live_mirror_list

Comment: Thank you ! It seems this little modification works. But it seems that the "rankmirrors" tool don't print anything, I'm digging... But you have answered to my first question ! :)